# How to speed up this C++ program with eigen library against matlab?

Tags: c++, matlab, eigen

I want to use C++ for big linear algebra computation. As a starting step, these comparison programs I created in C++ and matlab. I am also giving astonishing execution time here. Can you suggest way to beat matlab or atleast get comparable performance? I know that C++ uses highly vectorized methods for computations. So in large scientific programming involving linear algebra, should one always go for matlab instead of C++? I personally think that matlab doesn't give good performance for large computations therefore C++ is preferred to matlab in such cases. However my program results go contrary to this belief.

C++ program compiled with gcc:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen\Dense> //EIGEN library

using namespace Eigen;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
MatrixXd A;
A.setRandom(1000, 1000);

MatrixXd B;
B.setRandom(1000, 1000);

MatrixXd C;
C=A*B;
}
```

Execution time: 24.141 s

Here is matlab program:

```
function [  ] = Trial(  )
clear all;
close all;
clc;

tic;
A=rand([1000,1000]);
B=rand([1000,1000]);
C=A*B;
toc

end
```

Elapsed time is 0.073883 seconds.

Comment: Please detail the compiler and linker arguments (also specific versions) you used.

Comment: What switches did you compile the c++ program with? If you haven't done it, optimization can provide astronomical differences (use -O1 or -O2) or compile as release build.

Comment: I did not use any compiler arguments besides one for eigen library -I <path>.

Comment: You realize right that generating random numbers is pretty expensive. Maybe you should only count the time it takes to do the actual multiplication.

Answer (score 5):

It is extremely hard to beat `MATLAB`, even with all optimizations turned on. To get the most out of `Eigen` you need to compile with parallel support (`-fopenmp` in `gcc`), and turn optimizations on (`-O3`). Even in this case, `MATLAB` will be slightly faster, mainly because it is using the Intel MKL  proprietary library to get the most out of Intel chips, so unless you buy it I don't think you will be able to beat it. I am currently using `Eigen` for a project and wasn't able to beat `MATLAB` (at least not for dense matrix multiplication).

For example, for `A*B` where `A` and `B` are `1000 x 1000` complex matrices, the best average time I can get is:

`MATLAB`: 0.32 seconds
`Eigen`: 0.44 seconds

For `2000 x 2000`,

`MATLAB`: 2.80 seconds
`Eigen`: 3.45 seconds

System: MacbookPro 2013, OS X.

PS: you should make absolutely sure that you turn optimizations on (`-O3`) and also compile with parallel support, `-fopenmp`. This is the reason you're probably getting this huge difference in running time. So you should compile your program as:

```
g++ -O3 -fopenmp <other compiling flags/parameters> main.cpp
```

Comment: 'Using Windows 7, gcc version 4.7.0 20111219 (experimental) (GCC). 'g++ -O3 -fopenmp -I C:\MinGW\include file.cpp' gives undefined reference to `omp_get_num_threads, undefined reference to omp_get_thread_num. How I can compile with your options?

Comment: you have to link also with `-fopenmp`, can you please post the full Makefile or the command you use to compile ?

Comment: I did not use makefile, just used command 'g++ -O3 -fopenmp -I C:\MinGW\include file.cpp'

Comment: It seems that `-O3` is working fine but not `-fopenmp`. Any comments how to make that to work?

Comment: And with `-O3` option, now I can get runtime _0.466 s_. I guess proper use of `-fopenmp` can give better performance. Can anyone share makefile or compiler command?

Comment: I use `g++ -c -O3 -fopenmp <other flags> file.cpp`, then `g++ -fopenmp file.o` to link it. You still shouldn't get such a huge difference, I get something like 25% better for MATLAB, but not an order of magnitude better. If it still doesn't work, can try with `-L/path/to/libgomp -lgomp` when you link, or search how to link with `OpenMP` on Windows. I develop on Mac so it works for me.

Comment: @user3705273, I now realized that probably `libgmp` is not installed, can find on google how to install in on `cygwin`.

Comment: got it! doing settings on windows is bit tricky but finally got that. However matlab gives _0.62 s_ and gcc compiler gives _3.34 s_ for `2000 x 2000` matrix multiplication. I turned on `-03` and `-lmpi` still there is huge difference almost 5 times. Is there any way to further reduce execution time with gcc, c++ program?

Comment: @user3705273 make sure you turn on `openmp`, are you sure this is the flag and not `-fopenmp`? In my case, I get a difference but not at all as significat as you get.

Answer (score 5):

To get the best of Eigen, compile with optimizations ON (e.g. -O3 compiler flag), with OpenMP enabled (e.g., -fopenmp), and disable hyper-threading or specify to openmp the true number of physical cores (e.g., export OMP_NUM_THREADS=4 if you have 8 hyper-threaded "cores", but 4 physical cores).

Finally, you might also consider using the devel branch and enable AVX (e.g., -mavx) and FMA if your CPU does support FMA (e.g., -mfma).

Comment: ggael, was just curios, can you actually beat `MATLAB` without buying MKL? I like `Eigen` a lot but it is still a bit frustrating that `MATLAB` beats it by a narrow margin, is the MKL the whole reason why this happens? Is `MATLAB` using "fast" matrix multiplication, i.e. O(less than 3) operations?

Comment: For large dense matrix products, MKL is indeed very difficult to beat, and the room for possible improvements is extremely narrow since MKL is so close to the theoretical peak performance. On Haswell the devel version of Eigen does beat MKL ([dgemm](http://download.tuxfamily.org/eigen/gemm_double_Haswell.pdf), [sgemm](http://download.tuxfamily.org/eigen/gemm_float_Haswell.pdf)), but I guess that's because Intel does not care much about the laptop market for MKL. This is just a matter of time for them to catch up.

Comment: @KamKam: having 8 hyperthreaded “cores” means that there are 4 physical cores that each pretend to be 2 cores. By defining `OMP_NUM_THREADS=4` you ensure that each core only gets one thread, improving performance for heavy computation with heavy cache usage as is this case. If you don’t do anything, 8 threads would be the default. So setting `OMP_NUM_THREADS=8` is both pointless (it’s the default) and sub-optimal.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Matlab (if you don't buy the expensive parallel computing toolbox) hardly use multi-threading. It's only used in the libraries called by Matlab which are probably more efficient that what you're using now.

You can check this link to understand (and check) what libraries your Matlab uses http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/math-libraries-version-info-upgrade

It's also possible to use them in your C program (though they might have hidden the headers or something, at least you still have the .dll since they need that to run Matlab)

Comment: `MATLAB` uses A LOT of multithreading and very smart optimizations by default.

Comment: Even with 2014b, unless you're using very big matrices and some functions with large inputs, there is no multithreading. You can see it easily that Matlab isn't using all your CPU but just one core. The multitheading comes from the libraries called by Matlab and not Matlab itself by the way. If you DO have the parallel computing toolbox it changes though.

Comment: meneldal, you may be right, I have a full MATLAB toolbox installed. and the downvote is not from me :)